# ionic white screen when close modal

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

when open a modal it flashes with white screen and show the modal but when close the white screen show on android not in browser

```
$timeout(function() {
ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/_result.html', {
  scope: $scope,
  animation: 'slide-in-up',
  hardwareBackButtonClose: true,
  config: {
          // These options are available in ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.2 and up.
          scrollAssist: false,    // Valid options appear to be [true, false]
          autoFocusAssist: false  // Valid options appear to be ['instant', 'delay', false]
        }
 }).then(function(modal) {
  $scope.resultModal = modal;
});
```

Comment: I'm having this issue too, can't seem to find a solution. The white backdrop shows in browser, not on device. But it still flickers when closing, not as smooth as ionic samples. There's gotta be something messing with the styles or something, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've started my ionic v1 project with the side-menu starter app, 
it seems that when my HTML element or BODY receive "direction: rtl",
white screen happens, yet when I remove that css option the animation works fine..
currently I suspect that this has something to do with z-index although im not sure ( I dont have much experience in css animations )
I hope anyone with the same issue might benefit from this bit of information